# Where is New Relic API key?

Tags: wordpress, newrelic, w3-total-cache

I've installed Total Cache plugin in my wordpress application and it suggested me to create a New Relic account. I've done it, but now the plugin ask me for an API key, and no idea of where to find it. I thought it would be the license key, but not. Anyone know where is it?

Comment: Consider http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for questions like this.

Comment: Note that you will need to install New Relic's PHP agent to successfully monitor your W3 total cache information, which I'm not sure you've done yet. Without completing this step, adding the API key to total cache won't make more information available.

Comment: I've been having many problems since I try to configure New Relic. I tried to install APC in my VPS because Total Cache recommended it, but I didn't know that it was incompatible with PHP5.5 (instead have to use opcache), and VPS finally fell over (something that I touched about mysql server). Now, I'm not using New Relic or Total Cache. The last was causing many errors in my web page. But I'm not sure if opcache is working right... How can I know?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Sign in to the New Relic user interface.
2. Select (account name) > Account settings > Integrations > Data sharing > API access.
3. Click Enable API Access, and then make a note of your API key.

Above is copied from https://newrelic.com/docs/features/getting-started-with-the-new-relic-rest-api

**Update 20-Mar-2019**

With new version of New Relic

1. From the account dropdown in the New Relic UI, select Account
   settings > Integrations > API keys.
2. Select  Regenerate REST API key.
3. Select (Show key) to view your account's new REST API key.
4. Copy your account's REST API key to use with New Relic's REST API.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/getting-started/intro-apis/understand-new-relic-api-keys#creating

Hussain